# Ruby on Railsでの、アプリケーション固有の設定の定義の仕方を教えてください

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

アプリケーション固有の設定情報はどのように定義するべきでしょうか。

/config配下にmy_config.ymlを作成し、/config/initializers配下にmy_config.rbを作成したところエラーがでました。それぞれのファイルの内容は以下です。

my_config.yml:

```
COMMON: &COMMON
 author: "user name"
 logo:
  source: "http://www.wings.msn.to/image/wings.jpg"
  width:215
  height:67

development:
  hoge: "dev"
  <<: *COMMON

test:
  hoge: "test"
  <<: *COMMON

production:
  hoge: "pro"
  <<: *COMMON
```

my_config.rb:

```
MY_APP = YAML.load(File.read("/Users/*****/rails_projects/third_app/config/my_config.yml"))[Rails.env]
# *****はユーザー名
```

Comment: 「エラーがでました。」とありますが、どのようなエラーが出たのか具体的なエラーメッセージなどを書くと良い解答を得やすいと思います
http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

質問内容のプログラムでも問題なく動くはずですが、どのようなエラーが発生していますか？
環境に依存する値を管理するようなものとして、[Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro)や[dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)といったGemもあります。

Answer (score 0):

[RailsConfig](https://github.com/railsconfig/rails_config)  を利用すると、YAMLファイルから設定情報を読み込んで利用することが出来ます。設定は、RAILS_ENVごと (development, production, test, ...) に設定を分けて記載することもできます。

同じようなgemで [Settingslogic](https://github.com/settingslogic/settingslogic) がありますが、1年ほど更新されていないので避けた方が良いかもしれません。